# Comparing a specific character of an array index in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

What I'm trying to do is input numbers through a hash function, and storing the resulting hash into an array. I'm trying to find if any numbers result in similar hashes that match in the last characters. I'm trying to find the largest possible matching characters.

I have a hash array created.
My code is doing something like this:

> create hash array
>       i=1
>       do some computation with i, with a new result call it 'result'
>       then I put result into the hash pointing to what created it
>       hash[result]=i

so then I have something like this:

> {"abcd"=>1}
>       increment i
>       loop until some condition

So when I increment i, and I put it thru some computation again, I want to check if there is any similarities with the previous results, by first comparing the character at the end of the result

Say when I put 2 through my computations I result in "hwed", I want a way to compare and see that "abcd" and "hwed" match in the last character. Does anyone know how I can do this.

Comment: Feels like a hash isn't the right data structure for this kind of comparisons. Perhaps a suffix tree (or something similar) might be a better choice. Are all results always four characters long? Are you only interested in the last character or sometimes in longer suffixes?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually putting numbers through sha256 hashing, I'm storing the results, and trying to find if there are numbers that result in similar hashes, matching in a certain length. The resulting hash will always be length 64 after ive converted them into a string

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do (perform a sequence of operations and store each computation's result) can be done simply, though as often in Ruby there are many other potential ways to do it.

You haven't explained your problem well enough to understand what you're practically trying to achieve. But to help in a generic sense:

```
hash = {
  word1: { word: "cat", computations: [] }
  word2: { word: "dog", computations: [] }
  word3: { word: "pig", computations: [] }
}

hash.each do |key, val|
  # each key is a symbol and each val is a hash
  100.times do
    val[:computations] << val[:word].chars.shuffle.join
  end
end
```

So now the `computations` arrays are filled with 100 shuffles of the `word` string. At that point you can do whatever you need with the computations array (such as comparison)